# Scope resolution in templated inheritance (possibly what is called mixin)

Tags: c++, templates, scope-resolution

Suppose I have the templated classes

```
#include <iostream>

class A1 {
public:
  int x{314159};
};

template<typename Context>
class A2 : public Context {};

template<typename Context>
class A3 : public Context {};

template<typename Context>
class A4 : public Context {
public:
  int func() {
    return Context::A1::x;
  }

  int gunc() {
    return this->A1::x;
  }

  int hunc() {
    return A1::x;
  }
};

int main() {
  A4<A3<A2<A1>>> my_A;

  std::cout << "x = func() = " << my_A.func() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "x = gunc() = " << my_A.gunc() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "x = hunc() = " << my_A.hunc() << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Inside the definition of the templated class `A4`, at least when only the instance type `A4<A3<A2<A1>>>` is used, it seems to be possible to refer to `x` as either

```
this->A1::x;
```

or

```
Context::A1::x;
```

or

```
A1::x;
```

**Question 1:** Are these equivalent? Well, I think I can see them not being equivalent from the point of view of the templated class `A4` viewed in isolation. For `Context::A1::x` to work its template parameter should contain an `x`. For `this->A1::x` to work it should contain a scope called `A1`, which in turn should contain an `x`. And for `A1::x` to work the scope of `A4` itself should contain a scope called `A1` containing an `x`. *My intention is to ask if they are equivalent from the point of view of the type* `A4<A3<A2<A1>>>`.

**Nota bene:** gcc 8.2 with `-O03 -std=c++17` produces the same assembly code in each case. Namely, I compiled the code with only one of the functions `func`, `gunc`, and `hunc` and only one call to the corresponding one, and this compiler produced identical executables. Of course, strictly speaking this doesn't necessarily imply that for the language in abstract those expressions are equivalent.

**Question 2:** How does the 'unpacking' of the scope of `x` works in each case? Maybe this question doesn't make sense or is not exactly what I want to ask. Specially if the answer to Question 1 is that they are equivalent. Allow me modify this question after I find more information about Question 1, or ignore this question at first.

**Note to Question 2:** This observation might clarify why I am unsure how the unpacking works. If in the templated class `A4` we had one more method

```
int iunc() {
  return Context::Context::A1::x;
}
```

then the compilation fails with

```
memberTemplatedParent.cpp: In instantiation of ‘int A4<Context>::iunc() [with Context = A3<A2<A1> >]’:
memberTemplatedParent.cpp:48:45:   required from here
memberTemplatedParent.cpp:37:22: error: no type named ‘Context’ in ‘class A3<A2<A1> >’
 return Context::Context::A1::x;
                  ^
```

So, at least for `gcc` at the moment that the type instance of `A4` is being created, the template parameter of its template parameter is not a valid name (or I didn't name it properly in `Context::Context::A1::x`).

Comment: This has nothing to do with curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP). For details, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern

Comment: @Handy999 Thanks. This one is the one that is called mixins, is that the right name?

Comment: I am not sure about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Questions 1 and 2:

All versions are equivalent for the instantiation you have chosen. As long as it is not ambiguous, you can use the member `x` directly without specifying the scope. If the member is not in the current class, the base class is checked, and so further.

If you specify a particular base class and the member `x` is not there, again the base class is consulted.

For your particular specialization, you have

```
class A2<A1> : public A1 {};

class A3<A2<A1>> : public A2<A1>{};

class A4<A3<A2<A1>>> : public A3<A2<A1>> {
public:
  int func() {
    return A3<A2<A1>>::A1::x;  // fine: search for x in A1,
                               // where A1 is searched in A3<A2<A1>>
  }
  int gunc() {
     return this->A1::x; // fine: why not specifying A1 directly. The this pointer
                         // is not required here but adding does not cause any harm.
  }
  int hunc() {
     return A1::x; // fine: why not specifying A1 directly.
  }
  int iunc() {
     return x; // fine: would be possible as well
  }
```

};

Last question:

```
int iunc() {
  return Context::Context::A1::x;
}
```

reads as follows after template instanciation

```
int iunc() {
  return A3<A2<A1>>::Context::A1::x;
}
```

The compiler now complains that there is no typedef in the class `A3<A2<A1>>` which introduces the name `Context`. The template parameter is only visible within the class template.

Comment: I see. So, the rule is: The scope named `A1` is searched from the starting point in each case up the inheritance until it is found. Then inside it `x` is searched. In `A1::x` the starting point is the current scope. In `Context::A1::x` the starting point is the type passed to the parameter `Context`, which in my case is `A3<A2<A1>>`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In that case i think you are making inheritance (using template). So Context::x refers to the x property of the parent. in that case A3, since A3 doesn't overwrite this property, you have the same as A1::x.
In the second (gunc) you refer directly to the A1 using "this" thus no problem.
In the third one (hunc, which is not used so) that the same is gunc with an implicite reference to self. (but i'm not entirely sure)

Also if you add in the A2 class :

```
template<typename Context>
class A2 : public Context {
public :
    int x{45678};
};
```

The first one will print "45678"

If now you add in A3 while keeping A2

```
template<typename Context>
class A3 : public Context {
public :
    int x{67890};
};
```

the first output will be 67890

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. My fault. I missed both an `A1` in `Context::x`, and the last call to `hunc` instead of repeating a call to `gunc`. But your explanation helps me understand this better.